# How to change backcolor of textbox with keypress VB

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I need a little help with understanding how to change the .backcolor of  multiple text boxes.

What is of asked of me is this.

"Simulate a traffic light with 3 small square textboxes placed vertically on a form.  Initially, the top textbox will be green and the other 2 will be white.  When the tab key is pressed, the middle textbox turns yellow and the green box changes to white.  The next time the tab key is pressed, the bottom box turns red and the middle box turns white."

I can't figure out how to write the code as I am pretty new at this if someone could help me learn how to use .keypress I would really appreciate the help.

Comment: So which part are you having trouble with? Handling the form’s `KeyPress` event? Do you have any code?

Comment: (A “clever” way to do this would be using the textboxes’ focus, but that’s probably not what you’re looking for…)

Comment: where are you stuck? what have you tried?  Step One: make sure the 3 TB have the tab order that matches the assignment

Comment: In my mind I agree with minitech, the focus event would be the one to use, but to give you an idea you can assign the same event handler to multiple TextBox's, the sender object is the TextBox that has generated the event, you can then write code to determine which one is selected and make the appropriate background color changes.

Answer (score 0):

It would be easier to do if you used labels. Before you start, declare:

```
Dim count as Integer
```

To declare something, you put it under wherever it says: Public Class (...)

```
Private Sub keyreceive(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles MyBase.KeyPress
If e.KeyChar = Convert.ToChar(Keys.Tab) Then
trafficlights()
End If
End Sub

Sub trafficlights()
count += 1
topbox.BackColor = Color.White
middlebox.BackColor = Color.White
bottombox.BackColor = Color.White
If count = 1 Then
topbox.BackColor = Color.Green
End If
If count = 2 Then
middlebox.BackColor = Color.Yellow
End If
If count = 3 Then
bottombox.BackColor = Color.Red
count = 0
End If
End Sub
```